# Is there an API for user-defined song tags?

Tags: music

I am interested in collecting many user-defined tags for songs (primarily popular songs). These tags need to be descriptive of the song, but not standard metadata (like artist or album), because that information is very easy to obtain.

Comment: What do you qualify as 'tags'?  Are you looking for folksonomy style tagging (where people can enter whatever they want), or do you want ID3?  If it's ID3, [freeDB](http://www.freedb.org/) forked from CDDB when CDDB moved to a more restrictive license.

Comment: I would qualify tags as a labels for songs excluding metadata (i.e., factual data about the song). That website seems to only give metadata, so that wouldn't qualify it as tags.

Comment: just so you know, the ID3 metadata fields are typically called "ID3 tags" (the standard (1996) actually has [the string 'TAG' and then the values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v1)), and there's a 'genre' tag which is entered by whoever submits the entry ... which is why I asked for the clarification.  Tagging as you're using it (for user submitted free-text classification, where each user can submit different 'tags') is generally traced back to del.icio.us (2003).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last.fm lets certain users add/create tags for songs; not 100% sure who is a "certain user", but I'm assuming that it is related to longevity/activity on the site.
Here's a list of song tags that are included in the Last.fm dataset contribution submitted to the 1,000,000 song dataset:
http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/sites/default/files/lastfm/lastfm_unique_tags.txt
The Last.fm Dataset - Million Song Dataset
http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/lastfm
And of course Last.fm's API:
http://www.last.fm/api
Topped off by the `track.getTags` method call:
http://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getTags